# How to profile each single selenium test?

Tags: groovy, selenium, profiling

How can I monitor memory usage, database access and etc for each selenium test. I have a large project in groovy that fully uses selenium tests. I know how to use jprofiler, but it only monitors the whole memory/cpu usage and does not provide any information about single tests. Finally I want to be able to come up with some charts that shows memory usage for each test so I can detect the tests that are using huge amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Dynatrace might have the profiling tools you're looking for.  http://www.dynatrace.com/en/